# Print 10^15 size string in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to print a string combination of 's' based on user input. For example, if user input is 5 then the output will be 5 times of string 's'. 
I wrote a code like this.

```
a = int(input())
p =a*'s'
print(p)
```

It's working fine for small input. 
[image]

But it's is throwing *Memoryerror* for the large input. 
***What should I do if my input is 10^15?***
[image]

Comment: You check the value of `a` *before* you try to create a `str` that will clearly not fit in memory.

Comment: I'm afraid such a string can never fit into a traditional computer's memory

Comment: @Teja Is there any alternative way?

Comment: @ShaifulIslam It's rather odd but you could simply loop and print 's' with end='' instead of storing it in a variable

Comment: @Teja Thanks. It's working. But It's taking a long time. Please, Let me know if you've any idea to reduce the time. All I want to print a string which has n times of 's'.

Comment: Note that even if you do print 10^15 characters (perfectly possible using the current answer), *it will take a while*. On my system, it take about 5 µs per 100 characters which scales linearly with the number of characters. At this speed, printing 10^15 characters takes roughly 1.5 years.

Comment: @ShaifulIslam please look at Ann Zen's answer by modularizing your prints but be careful not to lose the remainder after your divide by say, 1000. Even then, for a big number like 10^15, it will take a really long time

Comment: @ShaifulIslam: What is this for? What possible purpose does printing 10^15 `"s"`s have? And why are you surprised that doing something a thousand million million times takes a long time? What you're asking for is not reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

You can see when the error occurs like this:

```
a = int(input())
for _ in range(a):
    print('s',end='')
```

Just let it run, and *if* there won't be an error, you will have to wait for an eternity for it to finish!

---

Or, for faster:

```
a = int(input())
for _ in range(a//100):
    print('s'*100,end='')
print('s'*(a%100))
```

---

... this should be fast enough:

```
a = int(input())
for _ in range(a//10000):
    print('s'*10000,end='')
print('s'*(a%10000),end='')
```

[image]

The squeezed boxes come amazingly fast.

Comment: Exactly what I proposed in the comments :)

Comment: Note that the ``//100`` version and similar will not produce the correct number of characters when the input is *not* evenly divisible by 100. You would have to take the input verbatim, then run a loop of ``for _ in range(a // 100):`` and afterwards once do ``print('s' * (a % 100))``.

Comment: I know, but it will never make it anyway, that's only used to roughly see when the memory error occurs.

Comment: @AnnZen Thanks. It's working. But It's taking a long time. Please, Let me know if you've any idea to reduce the time. All I want to print a string which has n times of 's' with the fastest way.

Comment: Did you try the `*1000` option?

Comment: Note that ``'s'*a%1000`` is not correct - it will multiply ``'s'`` by ``a``, then attempt printf style formatting. See my previous comment for the correct format.

Comment: Yes, I did. Still, time-consuming. But counting it as a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Change that to `10000` and things will get much faster because they will squeeze the lines ;)